# How to handle Url when there is no Record Id return?

Tags: apex, visualforce

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="OutofStockExtension">
<apex:outputLink value="/lightning/r/ContentDocument/{!PdfId}/view">Link to Out Of Stock Report</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class OutofStockExtension {
public id PdfId{get;set;}
public OutofStockExtension(){
    ContentDocument c = [select id from ContentDocument where Title ='Out-Of- 
Stock' LIMIT 1];
      PdfId=c.id;
}
}
```

Some times it is giving below error.

```
list has no rows for assignment to sobject
```

Can anyone tell me how to handle when there is no record return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?type=1&mode=1&id=000328824

The issue is that you're expecting 1 record by querying into a single sObject and this will throw an error if no rows are returned. If you simply just query into a list of sObject, then this exception would be prevented.

```
public Boolean urlValid{get;set;}
List<ContentDocument> cList = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Title = 'Out-Of-Stock'];
if(cList.size() > 0){
    urlValid = true;
    PdfId = cList[0].Id;
} else {
    urlValid = false;
}
```

The important question, though, is what should the logic be when there's no document pulled? The above code gives you an option as you can set it to some default document or even set a Boolean to use in the VF page to do something different in the UI (hide the component, etc).

```
<apex:page controller="OutofStockExtension">
<apex:outputLink value="/lightning/r/ContentDocument/{!PdfId}/view" rendered={!urlValid}>Link to Out Of Stock Report</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Kris thanks for your reply. I have tried this also but it is giving Error:  " Page doesn't exist
Enter a valid URL and try again" when there is no document return. I have to display any alert message when there no are records returned. I am using this VF Page in Lighting page and when i click on that link I am getting error.

Comment: Well because the URL is not valid. You'll need to update your VF page to handle the fact that sometimes you won't have an url. I mentioned this briefly, but you can use a boolean to dynamically hide the link and only show it when an id is returned in the apex